# How to deploy Microsoft Endpoint / InTune to computers that are in use already and not tied to Azure AD Accounts (Password Policy Failure)

Tags: microsoft-intune, mdm

We recently rolled out Microsoft Endpoint / InTune to our company computers.  Everything works great if the first time a user logs in it is with their Azure AD credentials.  We have computers that are in use already and we are running into a problem when those users add a work account (our Azure AD accounts) to enroll.  The devices are enrolled ok, but they are failing our password policy:

[image]

When I try to have them reset their passwords, they don't get the "Change Password" option when pressing ctrl + alt + delete.  We followed these directions: [Error -2016281112 when you deploy password policy in Microsoft Intune](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/error-deploying-password-policy)

So, we are stuck getting these devices compliant with our policies because there doesn't seem to be anyway to update their password to remove the password error.  I was hoping someone has hit this problem and can help us get past it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the devices are enrolled in intune?  Are you in a Hybrid domain enviornment or AAD only?